# "At x and y, I have encouraged..." or "At x and at y, I have encouraged..."?

Tags: grammar

I want to talk about two schools, x and y, in a sentence. I have the following options and I am confused which one is grammatically correct.
(1) At x and y, I have encouraged interaction between students.
(2) At x and at y, I have encouraged interaction between students.
(3) At both x and y, I have encouraged interaction between students.

Comment: All three are correct. Why do you think only one is?

Comment: I was not sure if all of them are grammatically correct.